# Can't install vagrant plugins in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I was trying to install vagrant plugin `vbguest`, but got following errors in terminal:

```
$ vagrant plugin install vbguest
Installing the 'vbguest' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:946:in `all=': undefined method `group_by' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/bundler.rb:275:in `with_isolated_gem'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/bundler.rb:231:in `internal_install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/bundler.rb:102:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:62:in `block in install_plugin'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:72:in `install_plugin'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:37:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:14:in `action'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:32:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in `each'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in `execute'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:56:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:268:in `cli'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:173:in `<main>'
```

I am using Virtual Box 5.0.18_Ubuntu r106667 and ruby 2.3.0p0. I also faced the same problem trying to install `sahara` plugin. How can I fix it?

Comment: this is a known issue already on some github posts. i think for now the only solution is to install them manually

Answer (score 67):

Yes, there is an issue: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7073 in `Vagrant 1.8.1`

PR with fix: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/7198

The fix should be released in `Vagrant 1.8.2`.

---

But until that you can patch it manually.

Here are the steps to fix `Vagrant 1.8.1` under `Ubuntu 16.04` which has `ruby 2.3.0`.

1.) Create file `vagrant-plugin.patch` with [the following contents](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=818237#28):

```
---
 lib/vagrant/bundler.rb | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb b/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb
index 5a5c185..c4a3837 100644
--- a/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb
+++ b/lib/vagrant/bundler.rb
@@ -272,7 +272,6 @@ module Vagrant

       # Reset the all specs override that Bundler does
       old_all = Gem::Specification._all
-      Gem::Specification.all = nil

       # /etc/gemrc and so on.
       old_config = nil
@@ -286,6 +285,8 @@ module Vagrant
       end
       Gem.configuration = NilGemConfig.new

+      Gem::Specification.reset
+
       # Use a silent UI so that we have no output
       Gem::DefaultUserInteraction.use_ui(Gem::SilentUI.new) do
     return yield
```

2.) Apply patch:

```
sudo patch --directory /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant < vagrant-plugin.patch
```

which fixes `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/bundler.rb`.

Comment: After applying the patch, I'm getting errors on vagrant up and vagrant halt http://pastebin.com/L2KwZ9iU , any ideas?

Comment: vagrant 1.8.3 the issue is still there https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7422

Comment: Never knew about the `patch` command, that's cool! Thanks for the fix!

Comment: I applied the patch on my `Lubuntu 16.04` and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of patching, I fixed the issue using vagrant v1.8.0 in ubuntu 16.04:

- Download package: `wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.8.0/vagrant_1.8.0_x86_64.deb`
- `sudo dpkg -i vagrant_1.8.0_x86_64.deb`
- `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`

Keep an eye and upgrade to 1.8.2 when it's released...
Enjoy!

Answer (score 8):

This is fixed in the recent version of Vagrant, so please upgrade it.

If you can't, run this command to fix the problem:

```
sudo sed -i'' "s/Specification.all = nil/Specification.reset/" /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/bundler.rb
```

<sup>Note: The `sudo` permission is required or run without as a root.</sup>

This will patch your `bundler.rb` file as per [PR (#7198)](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/7198/files).

You should also upgrade your `bundler` to at least 1.12.5 as per this vagrant [PR (#7404)](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/7404/files):

```
sudo gem install bundler --version ">= 1.12.5"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've same error with another plugin: `vagrant-triggers`

I've found a patch to apply on `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/bundler.rb`.

but so, vagrant enter in a big loop an try infinitely to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

Because nobody seems to have mentioned it so far, here's the here's the bug report for Ubuntu 16.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vagrant/+bug/1562696

As of now, nobody backported the patch for 16.04, so it seems to have to either [patch manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38277081/2015768) or [download a fixed package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37366676/2015768).

Answer (score 0):

updating ruby worked for me. Ubuntu 16.04.
I followed this guide https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2017/04/25/updated-ruby-ubuntu-packages/